# Active state on nav after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nav

This is the code I am using at the moment to add an active state to an item after your clicked on one of the navigation and the page has been redirected.

I was wondering if there was another way to do it because it works only on my local machine but not on a server.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {         
        current_page = document.location.href            
        if (current_page.match(/home/)) {
            $("ul#ulMenuNav li:eq(0) a").addClass('navActive');
        } else if (current_page.match(/about/)) {
            $("ul#ulMenuNav li:eq(1) a").addClass('navActive');
        } else if (current_page.match(/location/)) {
            $("ul#ulMenuNav li:eq(2) a").addClass('navActive');
        } else if (current_page.match(/staff/)) {
            $("ul#ulMenuNav li:eq(3) a").addClass('navActive');
        } else if (current_page.match(/contact/)) {
            $("ul#ulMenuNav li:eq(4) a").addClass('navActive');
        } else { 
            $("ul#ulMenuNav li a").removeClass('navActive');
        };

    });
```

Comment: Try inspecting `current_page` in the chrome debugger on your server to see what it is being set to. I think that is where your problem lies.

Comment: It would be better to do this on the server side if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this: http://jsfiddle.net/jaiprakashsah/thrDq/

```
var url = document.location.href;
var str = url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf('/'));
var nUrl = str.substr(str.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

$('ul#ulMenuNav li a:contains('+nUrl+')').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$(document).ready(function () {         
  var current_page = document.location.href;

  $('ul#ulMenuNav li a').removeClass('navActive');
  $('ul#ulMenuNav li a[href*="'+current_page+'"]').addClass('navActive');

});
```