# Change link to active onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a common header for all of the pages I have in my site.

When I click on any link it takes me to that page and the page gets refreshed.

But the header is the same as it was in the previous page.

What I want is that when I click on any link, that link gets bold(Active) and if I am on homepage the home link  should be active by default.

I am trying to work on this and when I click on any link the link gets active(bold) but as the page gets refresh and take me to the new page the link comes to non active(normal).

Here is my code.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$("#main-menu a").click(function() {
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
});>  
</script>
<style>
.active {font-weight:bold}
</style>
<!--Navigation-->
    <nav id="main-menu">
        <ul class="right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>                                    
        <li><a href="#">Test Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
      </nav>
```

Is there any way we can do it with the common header?
Thanks,

Comment: What server side language are you using?

Comment: Dublicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476591/active-state-on-nav-after-page-refresh

Comment: Please let me know if my answer worked for you or if you have any issues with the answer. Please accept my reply as correct answer if it worked for you- so that other users can benefit: from knowing that the answer works and by having the question marked as Answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is to pass values(state) between two pages via navigation. The best way to apply `.active`  to your current page is by checking what page you are on and then applying class via jquery

The `window.location.pathname` allows for path after the domain example if your site page is `www.my.example.com/page1` then it gives `path1`
Watch out for complicated cases like `www.my.example.com/category/page1` then it gives `category/path1`

A code like this would work. Also see fiddle link here http://jsfiddle.net/52Aqu/10/

```
$(window).load(function(){
   var checkvalue= window.location.pathname;
   //alert(checkvalue);
   $("a").each(function(){
                        if($(this).attr('href')== checkvalue)
                         { $(this).addClass("active");}
                         });

                    });
```

For you case when you actually want to check against the query parameter in url and query parameter in href,try this code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
   var checkvalue= window.location.search;
   //alert(checkvalue);
   $("a").each(function(){
                        var hrefvalue="?" + $(this).attr('href').split("?")[1];
                       //alert(hrefvalue)
            if(hrefvalue== checkvalue) { $(this).addClass("active");}
                         });
                    });
```

Here `location.search` property provides query parameters from URL. Example if page url is `www.example.com/sites/statics/static_page.html?name=global/canada/index` the `location.search` will have value `?name=global/canada/index`

and we check this against the split value from href

Comment: Hi DhruvJoshi, Thank you for taking effort to fixing my issue. Your code is very helpful. I need your help to implement this. But Coz linking i guess its not working for me. I have linked my url like this <a href="$field{site_url}/statics/static_page.html?name=global/canada/index"> . So when I run my page and click on any link it just take teh path till /site/statics/static_page.html. –

Comment: Thank you so much bhai. My issue is resolved. :)You are a genius.

Comment: Can you please see my one issue getting on this. If I click on any other link while being on the same page my header links  get non-active but when I am clicking on any header link eg:- Test Link 1, Test Link 2, Test Link 3 Its working perfectly fine. Thanks

Comment: Like these I have a link on the left side on my page. <a href="$field{site_url}/statics/static_page.html?name=global/canada/primary-oem-partnerships">

Comment: @RohitMehra the code i've given in answer will work through all links on page for checking. So if you click on a side link the page will reload with new url as something like `www.example.com/sites/statics/static_page.html?name=global/canada/primary-oem-p‌​artnerships` and now if this link is present anywhere on page it will be matched and get the `active` CSS class. Note that in this case no header will match the new path and hence will not get CSS class. Now **do you want to** add some rule that if the file path does not match any header links, by default some header should be `active`

Comment: Ok, no Thanks its fine for now.:)

Comment: worked, if using Jquery 1.8 and above, check the solution with the most votes on this answer as well.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38871753/uncaught-typeerror-a-indexof-is-not-a-function-error-when-opening-new-foundat

Answer (score 1):

You can check for example the `window.location.pathname` an compare it to the href of the navigation. Meaning:

```
var pathName = window.location.pathname;

$('nav a').each(function() {
    var $self = $(this);
    if($self.attr('href') ==pathName){
        $self.addClass('active');
    }
})
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You should not remove the class `active` of `a` but of `.active`. Basically this clears all the classes `.active` so that you can set it to the currently clicked link.

Script would look like:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$("#main-menu a").click(function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
});>  
</script>
<style>
.active {font-weight:bold}
</style>
<!--Navigation-->
    <nav id="main-menu">
        <ul class="right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>                                    
        <li><a href="#">Test Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3E2CT/)

Answer (score 1):

I Think this code can help you.

```
var url = document.location.href;  // Getting the url
var str = url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf('/')); // get the specific url
var nUrl = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1); // Get the page name from url

$('#menu li a').each(function(){
    if( $(this).attr('href') === nUrl){ // Comparing if we on the same page or not
        $(this).addClass('active'); // applying the class on the active page
    };
});
```